# SonarQube API search issues with componentKeys by directory

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-api

In the SonarQube docs it says that componentKeys can be the following:

> Comma-separated list of component keys. Retrieve issues associated to a specific list of components (and all its descendants). A component can be a portfolio, project, module, directory or file.

I want to get all the issues from components of a specific directory. I have tried to use the * wildcard like this:

`http://localhost:9000/api/issues/search?componentKeys=projectkey:src/testcases/*`

or

`http://localhost:9000/api/issues/search?componentKeys=src/testcases/*`

This doesn't seem to work, how can you search issues by a directory?

Comment: Was it resolved?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass your `projectKey` name as `ComponentKeys` and pull all the issues from the project.

```
http://localhost:9000/api/issues/search?componentKeys=testproject
```

Answer (score 0):

You were very close. If you want to filter issues under `src/testcases` then you can use:

```
http://localhost:9000/api/issues/search?componentKeys=projectkey:src/testcases/%
```